# jQuery: Get Totals of a Column using "PicNet TableFilter"

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, tablefilter

I am using **PicNet TableFilter** for my Table:
-http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet_table_filter.html

Example:
http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm

---

Now I need a **dynamic Totals Row**, which sums specific columns.

I found a script here:
*"Use jQuery to add all the values in a table column"*

http://naspinski.net/post/Use-jQuery-to-add-all-the-values-in-a-table-column_.aspx

---

I have implemented this script and I get the sum of columns, which I want. It works.

**But** if I use the PicNet- filter and filter the table, the "Total Row" does not change its values. They seem to be static.

I think the PicNet Script is too difficult to understand and edit.

The target is to get a Total Column Row, which changes dynamically depending on the filter usage.

---

I hope you can help me or have an idea for any alternative.

Thank you for every answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling your "summing" code in this TableFilter function: `filteredRows: function(filterStates) { call_SumCol(); }` See the TableFilter documentation.